# Programmatically register an OnLoad handler (for a form) in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to register an `OnLoad()` handler in code?

**Ex:**

A script is added as a **Form Library** (Customize Form etc.). It contains code that wants to be executed only after the form is loaded. I suppose it can be done by using `setTimeout()` / `setInterval()` - and check `Xrm.Page.data` object or so, but is there another way?

Comment: I'd go with timeout/interval depending on what you want to do (and when). I think he form loads before the ribbon does (certainly they load at subtly different times) so you need to be sure what it is you are verifying that has loaded and is ready to be manipulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why do you want to do it programmatically ?

- Form properties -> Event Handlers -> OnLoad -> Add -> put the function you want to execute after the form is loaded.

Otherwise, you can do it programmatically by using jQuery. Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // your code
});
```

Of course, you will have to add jQuery in your form's libraries.

Be careful using jQuery ready event. The data is retrieve asynchronously. The jQuery ready event may fire before the CRM is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

A very old question and answer, but so very wrong. Please don't do this using jQuery. Form events are registered in the formxml. If you want your code to work as part of a solution, you need to update the formxml in the same way that the UI would.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, and we have CRM 2016 now. Recently while trying to fix a bug in CRM 2016. 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/186877

I had the requirement to call/add a function e.g. `function abc()` `OnLoad` of `All Forms` of `All Entities`.

I have done it in below way.Hope this helps someone.

1. Download XrmToolBox from https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/
2. Using the `Form Libraries Manager` plugin in XrmToolBox add the JS files where `abc()` function is to all forms in CRM or Selected if you want as below.
3. In your JS file which you added to all Forms, add the following at first line.

   ```
   setTimeout(function () {
   abc();
   }, 1500);
   ```

[image]

Using the above procedure will CALL the `abc()` on Load of everyform without manually adding handlers on each and every form.